# element that is position absolute should stay next to other elements that are not

Tags: html, css, absolute

I would like to place elements automatically next to each other (i.e. elements could be added or removed so the elements have to change location). And one of the elements needs to expand and not push down the content beneath it.

This I hope makes its easier to understand: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEOxee

I want to make .absoluteit position absolute so it does not push down the content beneath it.

If i do this:

```
.absoluteit {
  background-color: red !important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

then it works except the red element covers another green element (again see the codepen)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this so that when I hover over the red item it expends the hidden content, but still stays in line with the other elements in its section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to position the `.right` element absolutely so that it's height or change of height does not affect the other elements.

See my example:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right .absoluteit {
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.absoluteit:hover .content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="absoluteit">absolute me
      <div class="content">content of absolute</div></div>
    <div >not me</div>
    <div>not me</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>this should not push down</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, so the hovered content is positioned absolute:

```
.absoluteit:hover .content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

if you dont want them to go over the green item in the next row, you need to give it a width.

Comment: kinda works except if i have a border around the red thing it does not work. The border does not cover the whole element including the hidden part: codepen.io/anon/pen/OEOxee

Comment: what do you want to do it? make a navigation with flexbox? not use js in a navigation? try this CSS flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and especially this demo https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/YqaKYR

Answer (score 1):

hope you are well,

can you just not absolutely position on hover:

```
.absoluteit:hover .content {
 display: block;
  position:absolute;
```

}

will this work for your solution?

Comment: kinda works except if i have a border around the red thing it does not work. The border does not cover the whole element including the hidden part: codepen.io/anon/pen/OEOxee

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the "this should not push" element as a sibling to the main div, a.k.a. it's mentioned AFTER the parent of the red div so it's technically always under the red div.

Try this:

```
  <div class="main">
  <div class="left">Left<br>
<div>this should not push down</div></div>
  <div class="right"><div style="float:left;">
    <div class="absoluteit">absolute me
  <div class="content">content of absolute</div></div></div>
    <div style="float:right;white-space:nowrap;"><div>not me</div></div><div style="float:right;white-space:nowrap;"><div>not me</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Move it inside of the Left Column div, then adding some more CSS here, like I did, should fix it

if main is the page header try:

```
  <div class="main" style="overflow-y:visible;height:20px;">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right"><div style="float:left;">
    <div class="absoluteit">absolute me
  <div class="content">content of absolute</div></div></div>
    <div style="float:right;white-space:nowrap;"><div>not me</div></div><div style="float:right;white-space:nowrap;"><div>not me</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>this should not push down</div>
```

And set the height of the main div to whatever you wish

Comment: ya but imagine main is the header of the page. and the "this should not push" is the rest of the page

Comment: again, main is the header of the page on all pages, so content comes after it so i cant have it in th left column

Comment: fixed it and header is seperate

Comment: that actually kinda fixes it, would have been cool to have main separated from content though. as in they are separate divs

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you are looking for:

```
.absoluteit {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.absoluteit:hover .content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

`.content` is positioned absolute relative `.absoluteit`, so the former does not affect the page layout and the latter stays in the original position.

Comment: kinda works except if i have a border around the red thing it does not work. The border does not surround the whole element including the hidden part: codepen.io/anon/pen/OEOxee